# CSS absolute positioning a table within a table

Tags: javascript, css, asp-classic, cross-browser, html-table

we have a table created by our (Classic) ASP code

It looks like this when we load the page...
[image]

When the user clicks the `Edit` button on the right of each record, the detail row is made visible...

In IE it looks like this (which is what we want):
[image]

Unfortunately, in Firefox and other browsers such as Chrome, it looks like this:
[image]

The code that creates this is server-side ASP code as below:

```
'For record editing
.Write("<TR class='rowsummary2' style=""display:none;"" id=tr_Edit" & g_lngRowCount & ">")
.Write("<td></td>")
.Write("<td></td>")
.Write("<td></td>")

.Write("<td colspan=""2"" class=""filterback"">")
'.write("<div style=""position:relative;left:150px; display:none;"" id=div_Edit" & g_lngRowCount & ">")
.Write("<table cellspacing=""2px"" cellpadding=""2px"" width=""100%"" border=""0"">")
    .Write("<tr>")
        .Write("<td class=""summaryheader2"" align=""left"" colspan=""2"">")
            .Write("<b>Edit ShPP</b>")
        .Write("</td>")
    .Write("</tr>")
    .Write("<tr>")
        .Write("<td align=""left"" width=""50%"">")
            .Write("<table width=""100%"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""2"" cellpadding=""2"">")                                   
                .Write("<tr>")
                    .Write("<td width=""20%"" class=""mandatory"">ShPP Amount Due</td>")
                    if not Null2Bool(adoRs("IsPaid")) then
                        .Write("<td colspan=""3""><input type='text' class='inputbox' name='txtShPPAmountDue' " _
                        & " id=txtShPPAmountDue" & g_lngRowCount _
                        & " value="  & formatnumber(adoRs("ShPPPayment"), 2,,,False) _
                        & " style='width:75px' onKeyPress='javascript: validKeyPressTest(/[0-9,.]$/, event)'" _
                        & " onblur='javascript: frmShPP.txtShPPPayment.value = this.value;'" _
                        & " ></input>")
                    else
                        .Write("<td class=""summarytext"">" & formatnumber(adoRs("ShPPPayment"), 2,,,False) & "</td>")
                    End if
                .Write("</tr>")

                .Write("<tr>")
                    .Write("<td valign=""top"" width=""20%"" class=""mandatory"">Reason</td>")
                    if not Null2Bool(adoRs("IsPaid")) then
                        .Write("<td colspan=""3"" class=""summarytext""><textarea " _
                        & " id=txtComment" & g_lngRowCount _
                        & " name=""txtComment"">" & null2str(adoRs("Notes")) & _
                        "</textarea></td>")
                    else
                        .Write("<td colspan=""3"" class=""summarytext"">" & null2str(adoRs("Notes")) & "</td>")
                    End if
                .Write("</tr>")
            .Write("</table>")
        .Write("</td>")
    .Write("</tr>")

    .Write("<tr>")
        .Write("<td class=""summaryheader2"" align=""right"" colspan=""2"">")
            if not Null2Bool(adoRs("IsPaid")) then
                .Write "<input title='Save' ID='btnSave" _
                        & g_lngRowCount _
                        & "' type='button' name='btnSave" _
                        & g_lngRowCount _
                        & "' value='Save' onclick=""javasript:checkAndSubmit('updaterow', " _
                        & adoRs("Period") _
                        & ")"" class='formbutton' onmouseover='this.className=&#39;formbuttonhover&#39;' onmouseout='this.className=&#39;formbutton&#39;' onfocus='this.className=&#39;formbuttonhover&#39;' onblur='this.className=&#39;formbutton&#39;'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"                           
            End if
            .Write "<input title='Cancel' ID='btnCancel" _
                    & g_lngRowCount _
                    & "' type='button' name='btnCancel" _
                    & g_lngRowCount _
                    & "' value='Cancel' onclick='javasript:CancelEdit(" _
                    & g_lngRowCount & ")' class='formbutton' onmouseover='this.className=&#39;formbuttonhover&#39; ' _onmouseout='this.className=&#39;formbutton&#39;' onfocus='this.className=&#39;formbuttonhover&#39;' onblur='this.className=&#39;formbutton&#39;'/>"                            
        .Write("</td>")
    .Write("</tr>")
.Write("</table>")
.Write("</td>") ' Filterback
.Write "</tr>"
```

the part of the ASP code that puts in the hiddren `TR` element containing the table is

```
.Write("<TR class='rowsummary2' style=""display:none;"" id=tr_Edit" & g_lngRowCount & ">")
.Write("<td></td>")
.Write("<td></td>")
.Write("<td></td>")

.Write("<td colspan=""2"" class=""filterback"">")
'.write("<div style=""position:relative;left:150px; display:none;"" id=div_Edit" & g_lngRowCount & ">")
.Write("<table cellspacing=""2px"" cellpadding=""2px"" width=""100%"" border=""0"">")
.Write("<tr>")
```

so for each record it's creating a row that is hidden with an id like `tr_Edit3` (for record 3) and **onclick** event of the `Edit` button the below javascript runs to show/hide the details table:

```
function HideEditTable(rowNum, IsPaid) {        
    var iTotRows = document.getElementById("txtRowCount").value;
    for (i = 1; i <= iTotRows; i++) {
        document.getElementById("tr_Edit" + i).style.display = 'none';
        //document.getElementById("div_Edit" + i).style.display = 'none';           
    }
    
    document.getElementById("tr_Edit" + rowNum).style.display = 'block';
    //document.getElementById("div_Edit" + rowNum).style.display = 'block';
    if (IsPaid == 0) {
        frmShPP.txtShPPPayment.value = document.getElementById("txtShPPAmountDue" + rowNum).value;
        frmShPP.txtNotes.value = document.getElementById("txtComment" + rowNum).value;
        frmShPP.txtLumpsum.value = false; // default
    }
}
```

So I need to have that "detail" or adjustment table always in the center in different browsers as it is in IE11 ...

I tried putting a `div` element around the table that I could position absolutely using css, but no luck (it messed it up but good!)

```
.Write("<td colspan=""2"" class=""filterback"">")
    '.write("<div style=""position:relative;left:150px; display:none;"" id=div_Edit" & g_lngRowCount & ">")
    .Write("<table cellspacing=""2px"" cellpadding=""2px"" width=""100%"" border=""0"">")
```

so how can I have that inner table always show in the middle?

thanks
Philip

Comment: wow, downvote straight away - at least tell me that I've added too much code and not explained enough!

Comment: This is essentially something for which the solution is client side.  It might help the js/css people if you use view source and display the relevant output code rather than the server side code which generates it.  (PS - the downvote didn't come from me)

Comment: I totally do not understand the downvote. I swear, sometimes it seems like there are people who go through all the asp-classic questions and downvote them, just because they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to get this to work, it turns out all we had to do was change the client side javascript

This doesn't work in FF/Chrome:

```
document.getElementById("tr_Edit" + rowNum).style.display = 'block';
```

But when we take out the `block` it magically works:

```
document.getElementById("tr_Edit" + rowNum).style.display = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a row in the table then you can target and center it with css:

```
tr {
    text-align: center;
}
```

or try it on the td